# Xamarin crashing on debug startup: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I'm very new to using Xamarin, I created a new Xamarin.Forms project and am attempting to make an app. However, sometimes it crashes immediately on starting up the emulator debugger, using all defaults recommended by Visual Studio 19. It will build fine, and then I will receive the following error:

```
  Message=Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView.setTextColor(android.content.res.ColorStateList)' on a null object reference
```

The Call Stack only has one item, [External Code], so it is of no use to me. I haven't changed much in any .xaml files, mostly back end work that has been done so far. Is there any reason this would be crashing in a near-default project?

Comment: One thing that might help us is to see what the code for where you are using your bottom nav view equivalent like. The exception says there is a null reference so that makes me think that how you are setting up that nav view is off

Comment: Can you please share us some relevant codes about BottomNavigationItemView and where you set textColor? It would be better If you can share us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).